# From IQueryable to TableQuery

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, azure-storage

Using Azure Storage 4.3.0 and in order to use `CloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync (TableQuery, TableContinuationToken)` I need to transform my LinQ predicate filter condition in a TableQuery, how can I do that?

in VB.NET

```
Dim q = MyTable.CreateQuery(Of MyEntity).Where(Function(e) e.PartitionKey = "MyPK")
'Where do I go from here to use ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind, in the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.Queryable` namespace I found my answer, IQueryable.AsTableQuery:

```
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.Queryable

[...]

Dim q = MyTable.CreateQuery(Of MyEntity).Where(Function(e) e.PartitionKey = "MyPK")

Dim qQueryable = q.AsQueryable

' And then I will properly loop on this
mySegToken = Await MyTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(qQueryable.AsTableQuery, mySegToken)
```